# c# SQL query Error with format dd.MM.yyyy

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, date, ms-access

Using format from Norway `dd.MM.yyyy` in my computer I've got syntax error when I try to get data from MS Access database. Query:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM DateTable WHERE StartDate BETWEEN #18.03.2016# AND #19.03.2016#"
```

If I change to other formats (my computer settings and in query) then everything is ok.

PD: I have the same problem using INSERT.
Thanks

Comment: That's one of the reasons to use parameterized queries

Comment: Use SQL Parameters - the provider objects know how to pass a NET DateTime type to the underlying DB correctly (in part because they dont convert to text).  That looks like Access notation, so why the MySQL tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using ISO date format like YYYY-MM-dd for both INSERT/UPDATE and SELECT operations. This will format be understood correctly both by database and .net. The format of date is just a cosmetic issue about displaying. When you have a correct date object you can show it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks! It's working with all the formats that i need.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your code but if you insist on creating SQL strings you must format the string expressions for the date values to read like this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM DateTable WHERE StartDate BETWEEN #2016/03/18# AND #2016/03/19#"
```

Comment: I have data in Access Database. Datagrid (WPF) will be filled with data coming from this database but filtered by dates that user can choose using a datepicker. So i will have a DateTime type as data to use a filter.. Each user can have a different format in their computer.

Comment: The format has no influence; it is for display only.

Comment: Anyways, I tried this format yyyy/MM/dd and it's working for all the optiond that i need. Thanks you!

Comment: OK, then please mark as answered. Also, I meant the format the user's machine may use ... the format of the string expressions for the date values in the code does matter, of course.